# output files from a second directory in same php function

Tags: php, directory, scandir

I have the following code to output images from directory im/, how can I tweak this to also output images from another diectory called out/ (for example)? As to echo another img tag under the current one?

```
<?php
    $imgDir = "im/";

    $images = scandir($imgDir); 
    $ignore = array( ".", ".." ); 

    natsort($images);

    foreach($images as $file)
       {
    if(!in_array($file, $ignore))
       {
    echo "<div id=\"slideWrapper\">\n";
    echo "<img src=\"im/$file\" width=\"1000\" height=\"683\" alt=\"$files\" />\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
    };
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do it the following way - exchanged $imgDir for an array. The $images array now contains both path and filenames.

```
<?php
    $imgDirs = array("im/", "out/");
    $images = array();

    // take one of the given directories
    foreach($imgDirs as $imgDir)
    {
       // open a directory reader for this given directory
       $dh = opendir($imgDir);
       // read a single filename of this directory (stop loop if there is no more file)
       while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) 
       {
           // ignore '.' and '..'
           if($filename != '.' && $filename != '..')
           {
              // add the directory and filename to the images array
              // all images, regardless of the folder, are stored in one array :)
              $images[] = $imgDir . $filename;
           }
       } 
       closedir($dh);
    }

    natsort($images);

    // loop for every image
    foreach($images as $file)
    {
       // for every img, echo a div-img-/div-combination
       echo "<div id=\"slideWrapper\">\n";
       echo "<img src=\"$file\" width=\"1000\" height=\"683\" alt=\"$file\" />\n";
       echo "</div>\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: if you'd like to retrieve the image dimensions from file, please use: http://php.net/manual/de/function.getimagesize.php.

Comment: Ok that makes sense thanks! But if I was to output osmething like this :
<div>
<img src="im/" />
<img src="out/" />
</div>

As i need to have one image of each directory in two seperate img tags?

Comment: with the above code, you get a div-img-/div-combination for every image, regardless of the folder they are in. i added comments for clarification.
do you need to group the images?

Comment: Yep! and thanks for clarifying. I need a div-img(from im/)-img(fom out/)-div. For example for every image named x.jpg in one folder the image names x1.jpg from the other folder is echoed underneath.

Comment: and it is guaranteed that for every x.jpg in folder 1, a x1.jpg in folder 2 exists?

Comment: Yes, could be 1 or t or anything. I know this might not be the best way around it but ultimately i need to output two images that go together (by filename or else) and print them out so that they are in the same div

Answer (score 0):

believe this would fit your needs.

```
<?php
    $imgDir = 'im/';
    $imgDir2 = 'out/';
    $images = array();

    // open a directory reader for the first directory
    $dh = opendir($imgDir);
    // read a single filename of this directory (stop loop if there are no more files)
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) 
    {
        // ignore '.' and '..'
        if($filename != '.' && $filename != '..')
        {
           // add the directory and filename to the images array
           $images[] = $filename;
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);

    natsort($images);

    // loop for every image
    foreach($images as $image)
    {
       // for every img, echo a div-2-images-div-combination
       echo '<div id="slideWrapper">';
       echo '<img src="'.$imgDir . $image.'" width="1000" height="683" alt="'.$image.'" />';
       echo '<img src="'.$imgDir2 . $image.'" width="1000" height="683" alt="'.$image.'" />';
       echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

I would recommend using single quotes, as you don't have to escape normal quotes and it's faster :)

Comment: Thank you for your time henchman, slowly getting a grasp of all of this!